# flask for python 3.5 on droplet (VirtualOcean)

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, flask

I created a droplet with Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on digOcean. Python 3.5.2 comes preinstalled but being somewhat clueless I followed a tutorial (book: Flask by Example) and:

```
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install python-pip

$ pip install --user Flask
```

I then installed the apache server with :

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2

$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

I got the server running but the error is that there is no module flask. I found that flask was installed for python 2.x but apache runs python 3.x.

I can not figure out how to either a) install flask for python 3.x or b) get apache to run python 2.x

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Install `pip3`:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

Then install Flask using `pip3`:

```
$ pip3 install flask
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Flask running with Python 3.5 using these package versions:

```
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
blinker==1.2
Flask~=1.1.0
```